# powershell script to get both size and size on disk of directory

Tags: powershell

I was writing a power shell script to get a size of directory

```
(get-childitem <path> -recurse | measure-object -property length -sum).sum/1MB
```

now I want both "size" and "size on the disk" of a folder to be displayed as output

Comment: "I want x" isn't a question; If you mean "someone work out how to do it, code it, and then give me the answer", that's too broad to be on-topic. "Size on the disk" is not a simple value, nor is it calculated in the same way for different versions of Windows - see https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160427-00/?p=93365 -
 and that's not including: hidden and system files (needs `gci -force`), long paths in PowerShell, deciding what to do about permissions which block access, NTFS junctions, server features like NTFS deduplication, other PSProviders apart from FileSystem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
GCI <Path> -Recurse |
Group-Object -Property Directory | % {
  New-Object psobject -Property @{
    Name = $_.Name
    Size = ($_.Group | ? {!($_.PSIsContainer)} | Measure-Object Length -Sum).Sum
  }
} |
Sort-Object -Property Size -Descending
```

Comment: Epic code.  I've added some indentation to try and make it more obvious what it's doing.  Hope that's helpful.

Comment: This is only "size".  OP wanted "size on disk" also.